# Can you convert a .smali into .jar

Tags: java, jar, smali

Is there a possibility to convert a smali byte code into a jar. I have tried using Baksmali to do the reverse from odex to smali but is there a way to go backwards to jar itself

Comment: A jar file is just an a zip file.  So you can convert anything into a jar file.  Do you actually want to convert ".dex" files to ".class" files?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. See [enjarify](https://github.com/google/enjarify) or [dex2jar](https://github.com/pxb1988/dex2jar). Both take a dex file, and output a jar file with the converted java .class files.

And of course, you can use [smali](https://github.com/JesusFreke/smali) to first convert the smali files back to a dex file.

Comment: What if I have odex file and I want to convert to Jar. Because in this case, I have smali bytecode which I want to convert to jar @JesusFreke